# Multiple string replacements

Tags: xslt-3.0, xpath-3.1

(updated question from 'static replace' to 'dynamic replace')

```
<data>
  <replacements>
    <replace key="greeting" value='Hello' />
    <replace key="name" value='Donald' />
  </replacements>
  <rules>
    <rule key="GREETING" value="replacements/replace[@key='greeting']/@value" />
    <rule key="NAME" value="replacements/replace[@key='name']/@value" />
  </rules>
  <text>
    GREETING NAME duck.
  </text>
</data>
```

I'd like to replace the text in the element `text` with every occurrence of a key in all the rules. The replacement text is the evaluation of the attribute `value` in that element.

Which approach should I take (using the newest Saxon HE)?

The result of the text should be “Hello Donald duck.”

---

Addition:

I think part of the problem can be solved with `<xsl:evaluate>`, but this is obviously not working yet (no string replacements):

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0" >
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:evaluate xpath="/data/rules/rule[1]/@value" context-item="." />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is `<data value="Hello"/>`. What I see is the dynamic evaluation of the xpath expression, and from there it should be possible to do the string replacement.

Now my step would be to add my approach to Martin's answer, but this would be mixing XSLT in XPath, which does not work that way I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying with `xsl:evaluate`, consider to show your code if you mention it, but it seems `fold-left` calling `replace` suffices:

```
  <xsl:template match="text" expand-text="yes">
    <xsl:copy>{fold-left(../rules/rule, ., function($a, $r) { replace($a, $r/@key, $r/@value) })}</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="data/rules"/>
```

With the more complicated structure of your "replacement rules and data" you could use

```
  <xsl:function name="mf:evaluate-value">
    <xsl:param name="rule" as="element(rule)"/>
    <xsl:evaluate context-item="$rule/../.." xpath="$rule/@value"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="text" expand-text="yes">
      <xsl:copy>{fold-left(../rules/rule, ., function($a, $r) { replace($a, $r/@key, mf:evaluate-value($r)) })}</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="data/rules | data/replacements"/>
```

For the use function you need to declare a namespace in the stylesheet e.g. `xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"`.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my question. I apologise for not being clear about evaluation, next time I try to be more precise.

Comment: @topskip, so far you haven't shown any code using/trying to use `xsl:evaluate`.

Comment: I have added my (non working) code to the question.

Comment: @topskip, see whether the added code covers your more complicated requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much. I need to learn more XSLT/XPath 3 stuff.

Comment: Thanks again. After a few days I playing with the answer (and extending it,...), I have found it very valuable for my XSLT/XPath 3 journeys!